# Temporary/"non-addressable" fixed-size array?

Tags: c++, intrinsics

The title is in lack of a better name, and I am not sure I managed to explain myself clearly enough. I am looking for a way to access a "data type" via an index, but not force the compiler to keep it in an array. The problem occurs in writing a low-level code based on SSE/AVX intrinsics.

For ease of programming I would like to write code as the following, with *fixed-length* loops over "registers" (data type `__m512`):

```
inline void load(__m512 *vector, const float *in)
{
    for(int i=0; i<24; i++)
        vector[i] = _mm512_load_ps((in + i*SIMD_WIDTH));
}
// similarely: inline add(...) and inline store(...)

void add(float *in_out, const float *in)
{
    __m512 vector1[24];
    __m512 vector2[24];

    load(vector1, in_out);
    load(vector2, in);
    add(vector1, vector2);
    store(in_out, vector1);
}
```

The fact that `vector1` and `vector2` are defined as arrays appears to be troublesome for the compiler (`icc` in my case): it seems to be forced to make it "addressable", keeps it on the stack, and thus generates a lot of `load` and `store` instructions that I do not need. As far is I understand this is to allow for pointer arithmetics with `vector1` or `vector2`.

I would like the compiler to keep everything *only* in registers. I know that this *is* possible: if I write the code without the `__m512` arrays but many *individual* `__m512` variables the compiler generates better code.

Solutions:

I (unsuccessfully) tried using a class like the following (I had hoped that the switch-statement and everything else would get optimized out):

```
class Vector
{
    inline __m512 & operator[](int i)
    {
        switch(i)
            case 0:  return component0;
            // ...
            case 23: return component23;
    }

    __m512 component0;
    // ...
    __m512 component23;
};
```

I have also considered macros, but could not find a good solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Simon

Following a comment in an answer below, here a more detailed example of what I want to do (this is still a simplification though):

```
inline void project(__m512 *projected_vector, __m512 *vector)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        projected_vector[i] = _mm512_add_ps(vector[i], vector[i+3]);
}

inline void matrix_multiply(__m512 *out, const float *matrix, __m512 *in)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        out[i] = _mm512_mul_ps(  matrix[3*i+0], in[0]);
        out[i] = _mm512_fmadd_ps(matrix[3*i+1], in[1], out[i]);
        out[i] = _mm512_fmadd_ps(matrix[3*i+2], in[2], out[i]);
    }
}

inline void reconstruct(__m512 *vector, __m512 *projected_vector)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        vector[i] =   _mm512_add_ps(vector[i], projected_vector[i]);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        vector[i+3] = _mm512_sub_ps(vector[i], projected_vector[i]);
}

inline void hopping_term(float *in_out, const float *matrix_3x3, const float *in)
{
    __m512 vector_in[6];
    __m512 vector_out[6];
    __m512 half_vector1[3];
    __m512 half_vector2[3];

    load(vector_in, in);
    project(half_vector1, vector_in);
    matrix_multiply(half_vector2, matrix_3x3, half_vector1);
    load(vector_out, in_out);
    reconstruct(vector_out, half_vector2);
    store(in_out, vector_out);
}
```

Comment: If you want to go the macro route, and don't want to do all the voodoo yourself, P99 may have something useful: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/

Comment: I don't know anything about SSE/AVX, but it seems like a custom vector with proxies would be useful.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck: could you elaborate more? Isn't `class Vector` given as a possible solution in the question something like a proxy to `__m512 component0 ... component23`? My approach did not bring the desired effect, what would you change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an answer to my own question: I have come up with a solution based on a combination of templates and macros.

- a `struct` holds the "vector" of `__m512` variables
- a template function is used to access elements of the `struct`
- the index to the vector is passed as a template parameter, so the compiler manages to optimize away the switch statement in the access function
- we cannot use a c-loop over the template parameter, so a variadic macro is used to mimic loops

Example:

```
struct RegisterVector
{
    __m512 c0;
    __m512 c1;
    __m512 c2;
    __m512 c3;
    __m512 c4;
    __m512 c5;
};

template <int vector_index> __m512 &element(RegisterVector &vector)
{
    switch(vector_index)
    {
        case  0: return vector.c0;
        case  1: return vector.c1;
        case  2: return vector.c2;
        case  3: return vector.c3;
        case  4: return vector.c4;
        case  5: return vector.c5;
    }
}

#define LOOP3(loop_variable, start, ...) \
    do { \
    { const int loop_variable = start + 0; __VA_ARGS__; } \
    { const int loop_variable = start + 1; __VA_ARGS__; } \
    { const int loop_variable = start + 2; __VA_ARGS__; } \
    } while(0)

// simple usage example
LOOP3(c, 0, _mm512_add_ps(element<2*c+0>(vector1), element<2*c+1>(vector2)));

// more complex example: more than one instruction in the loop, cmul and cfmadd itself are inline functions for a complex mul or fmadd
LOOP3(r, 0,
    cmul  (su3[2*(3*0+r)+0], su3[2*(3*0+r)+1], element<2*0+0>(in), element<2*0+1>(in), element<2*r+0>(out), element<2*r+1>(out));
    cfmadd(su3[2*(3*1+r)+0], su3[2*(3*1+r)+1], element<2*1+0>(in), element<2*1+1>(in), element<2*r+0>(out), element<2*r+1>(out));
    cfmadd(su3[2*(3*2+r)+0], su3[2*(3*2+r)+1], element<2*2+0>(in), element<2*2+1>(in), element<2*r+0>(out), element<2*r+1>(out)));
```

As you can see you can do integer arithmetic in the template arguments as usual, and the loop index can also be used to access other arrays.

The `LOOP` macro could probably still be improved, but for my purposes it is sufficient.

Simon

Comment: cool! I'm glad you found a solution that works for you. I'm not good at C++ any more. Each day I move further and further away from C++ and closer to C. I just started writing assembly code with NASM. Incidentally, are you using the Intel XeonPhi? How do you have access to AVX512?

Comment: Yes it is for the Xeon Phi. The intrinsics you see in my code are those for the Xeon Phi. They are not identical to AVX512, but very close and, I guess, often look identical. See here: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/index.htm#GUID-FC13EE09-8555-414B-8FF2-D7D66CD3975C.htm

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar to this recently using template meta programming. In the following code I think you just need to replace `_mm256` with `_mm512` and change the `SIMD_WIDTH` to `16`. This should unroll your loop 24 times.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

#define SIMD_WIDTH 8
#define LEN 24*SIMD_WIDTH

template<int START, int N>
struct Repeat {
    static void add (float * x, float * y, float * z) {
        _mm256_store_ps(&z[START],_mm256_add_ps(_mm256_load_ps(&x[START]) ,_mm256_load_ps(&y[START])));
        Repeat<START+SIMD_WIDTH, N>::add(x,y,z);
    }
};

template<int N>
    struct Repeat<LEN, N> {
    static void add (float * x, float * y, float * z) {}
};


void sum_unroll(float *x, float *y, float *z, const int n) {
    Repeat<0,LEN>::add(x,y,z);  
}
```

When I compile with `g++ -mavx -O3 -S -masm=intel` the assembly looks like

```
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx], ymm0
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx+32], ymm0
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+64]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+64]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx+64], ymm0
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+96]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+96]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx+96], ymm0
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+128]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+128]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx+128], ymm0
    ...
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+736]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+736]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdx+736], ymm0
```

I have used this method successfully recently where I'm trying to push through 4 micro ops at once (more using fusing). For example to do two loads, one store, and one two FMA in one clock cycle. I checked the results to make sure there were no errors. I was able to increase the efficiency a bit in a few of my tests doing this.

Edit: Here is a solution based on the OPs updated question. I have had problems using arrays for SIMD variables in the pass as well so I don't usually use arrays with them. Also, due to register renaming I rarely have to use many SIMD registers (I think the most I have used is 11). In this example only five are necessary.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

#define SIMD_WIDTH 8

static inline __m256 load(const float *in) { 
    return _mm256_loadu_ps(in);
}

inline void store(float *out, __m256 const &vector) {
    _mm256_storeu_ps(out, vector);
}

inline __m256 project(__m256 const &a, __m256 const &b) {
    return _mm256_add_ps(a, b);
}

inline void reconstruct(__m256 &vector1, __m256 &vector2, __m256 &projected_vector) {
    vector1 = _mm256_add_ps(vector1, projected_vector);
    vector2 = _mm256_sub_ps(vector1, projected_vector); 
}

class So {
public:
    __m256 half_vector[3]; 
    So(const float *in) {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
            half_vector[i] = project(load(&in[i*SIMD_WIDTH]), load(&in[(3+i)*SIMD_WIDTH]));
    }

    __m256 matrix_multiply(const float *matrix) {
        __m256 out;
        out = _mm256_mul_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(&matrix[0]), half_vector[0]);
        out = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(&matrix[1]), half_vector[1], out);
        out = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(&matrix[2]), half_vector[2], out);
        return out;
    }
};

void hopping_term(float *in_out, const float *matrix_3x3, const float *in)
{   

    So so(in);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        __m256 vector_out1, vector_out2;
        __m256 half_vector2 = so.matrix_multiply(&matrix_3x3[3*i]); 
        vector_out1 = load(&in_out[i*SIMD_WIDTH]);
        reconstruct(vector_out1, vector_out2, half_vector2);
        store(&in_out[(0+i)*SIMD_WIDTH], vector_out1);
        store(&in_out[(3+i)*SIMD_WIDTH], vector_out2);
    }
}
```

This only uses five AVX registers. Here is the assembly

```
    vmovups ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rdx]
    vmovups ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
    vaddps  ymm3, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+96]
    vmovups ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+64]
    vaddps  ymm2, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+128]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+160]
    vmulps  ymm1, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
    vfmadd231ps     ymm1, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+4]
    vfmadd231ps     ymm1, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+8]
    vaddps  ymm4, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    vsubps  ymm1, ymm4, ymm1
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm4
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+96], ymm1
    vmulps  ymm1, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+12]
    vfmadd231ps     ymm1, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+16]
    vfmadd231ps     ymm1, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+20]
    vaddps  ymm4, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32]
    vsubps  ymm1, ymm4, ymm1
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32], ymm4
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+128], ymm1
    vmulps  ymm3, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+24]
    vfmadd132ps     ymm2, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+28]
    vfmadd132ps     ymm0, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32]
    vaddps  ymm1, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+64]
    vsubps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+64], ymm1
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+160], ymm0
```

Comment: I am not sure if this does what I want. Maybe it got lost in the brevity of the example. As far as I understand this basically uses recursion to avoid writing loops, i.e., to do the unrolling. But unrolling is not the problem in my code: the compiler does that well enough. How would your solution work in a more complex example, where you do more than a simple "add", i.e., load the vector, do 3-5 instructions, store vector. Note that the 3-5 instructions may mix the vector elements in my case.

Comment: @Simon, this technique works well if the operations are independent. I don't think 3-5 more compute instructions would make a difference as long as they are independent. If you're mixing elements or doing a reduction then I'm not sure how to use template meta-programming for that. Currently I still do that "by hand".

Comment: @Simon BTW GCC's `-funroll-loops` only unrolled eight times. I wanted more. That's why I did it this way. GCC also used too many registers. Due to register renaming the unrolling above only uses one logical register.

Comment: @Simon, can you give a more specific example (edit your question with some code) of what you want to and why my method does not work. Then I can try and find a different solution.

Comment: @Simon, I updated my answer based on your edit. I have also had some troubles using arrays for SIMD variables so I usually avoid this. I usually explicitly list each one. In this case it worked out. But the main point is that you often don't need that many registers due to register renaming. In the example you showed I only needed five SIMD registers. Your code requested 18.

Comment: @Z boson: Thanks for your effort. But I have to admit that this way of writing it is exactly what I wanted to avoid. One reason is, for example, that I actually am dealing with *complex* numbers, so say the function `matrix_multiply` would have at least 9 arguments, and things start to get messy.

Comment: @Simon, well I'm afraid I don't know a better way yet. I like your question. I hope someone has a better answer because it would help me as well. Personally I try and keep as much of the calculation in one function so that many variables are not being passed around.

Comment: @Simon, I edited my answer and changed the code so that it no longer has to pass the three matrix elements. I used a class I called `So` to do this. This method could be extended to hold many more registers. The resulting assembly code is the same.

Comment: @Z boson, I have found a solution that works for me, see my answer to the question.